# Powershell check script run time and kill script if longer than x minutes

Tags: powershell, time

Hello my question today is how to figure out how long a powershell script has been running for. I did find something to figure out what specific powershell script has been running by using 
`PowerShell -File test1.ps1`

then using

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "NAME='PowerShell.EXE'"
```

However this, as far as i can see, does not tell me how long the powershell script has been running for. Is there a way to find how long a powershell script has been running for and kill it without writing some kind of time function inside the powershell script that is running? Also is there a way to stop that script if it has been running for longer than "x" minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$time = get-date
do
{
    bla-bla-bla
}
while ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) -le $time)
```

To do something for 5 minutes